# materializecss collapsible panel with a different html structure

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular-material, materialize

I'm trying to create a custom collapsible panel using materialize but I don't know why the button is not triggering and showing the panel body. I have created a fiddle with my custom example that doesn't work and one materilaize example with their structure that works.

From my inspect I saw that the active class is not being added on panel body while clicking on panel header which is quite strange.

So if anyone can help me with that please ... modifying materialize components is like a pain in the ass !

```
 <div class="collapsible">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="1left">Left</div>
      <div class="2center">Center</div>
      <div class="3right">Right
        <a class="collapsible-header">Colapse header</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="collapsible-body">
    This should be the body collapsed
  </div
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zt5515zt/90/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Materialize you need both **collapsible-header** and **collapsible-body** at the same level in order to make **Collapsible** work.

Just Change the level of you **collapsible-body** as shown below and it will work.

```
<a class="collapsible-header">Colapse header</a>
<div class="collapsible-body">
  This should be the body collapsed
</div>
```

Hope this helps you solve the problem.